# How to convert this Access inner join query into SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update

I want to write an update statement that compares the new code table to the old code by joining on the MASTER_ID.  Then If the NEW_CODE.CODE = 1234 AND OLD_CODE.CODE_ID is not in the CODE_MAPPING table then SET NEW_CODE.CODE_ID = OLD_CODE.CODE_ID AND NEW_CODE.SEQ_NO = OLD_CODE.SEQ_NO.  This is what I have so far but it does not seem to correctly update if I get a null value in the CODE_ID column.  I think I need to do a self join but nothing I do seems to work any help would be greatly appreciated.

I have three tables with the following data:

```
**NEW_CODE**

    MASTER_ID     SEQ_NO     CODE_ID     CODE
    100            0          XX         1234
    200            0                     5555
    300            0          XX         1234
    300            0          XX         1234

**OLD_CODE**

   MASTER_ID   SEQ_NO   CODE_ID
   100          1        D1           
   200          1        A1
   300          1        
   300          2        Z1

**CODE_MAPPING**

   CODE_ID
   A1
   B1
   C1
   D1
```

**UPDATE STATEMENT:**

```
UPDATE NEW
  SET SEQ_NO = OLD.SEQ_NO,
  CODE_ID = OLD.CODE_ID

  FROM NEW_CODE       NEW
  INNER JOIN OLD_CODE      OLD
  ON NEW.MASTER_ID = OLD.MASTER_ID

 LEFT JOIN CODE_MAPPING       CM
  ON OLD.CODE_ID = CM.CODE_ID
  WHERE NEW.CODE = 1234 
  AND CM.CODE_ID IS NULL
```

The updated table should look like this:

```
 **UPDATED NEW_CODE**

        MASTER_ID     SEQ_NO     CODE_ID     CODE
        100            0          XX         1234
        200            0                     5555
        300            1                     1234
        300            2          Z1         1234
```

So the only thing that should update is the two rows with a MASTER_ID of 300.  But for some reason I am getting the following result instead:

```
 **CURRENT RESULT NEW_CODE**

        MASTER_ID     SEQ_NO     CODE_ID     CODE
        100            0          XX         1234
        200            0                     5555
        300            2          Z1         1234
        300            2          Z1         1234
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have two rows with same identifier (MASTER_ID), tsql is needed instead of a simple statement.

Precondition for rows to update:
Every row in NEW could be matched to one row in OLD and reverse. 
We need a criteria to identify updated rows in NEW. I use SEQ_NO=0 here.

1. a unique key for each row in OLD and NEW is needed. Your example data don't contain a unique key. So I add one to OLD and one to NEW. It can be dropped in the end.

   alter table OLD add IDX int IDENTITY(1,1)
   alter table NEW add IDX int IDENTITY(1,1)
2. declare a cursor on OLD (only rows to be updated)

   DECLARE @IdxOld int
   DECLARE @IdxNew int

   DECLARE MY_CURSOR CURSOR 
     LOCAL STATIC READ_ONLY FORWARD_ONLY
   FOR 
   SELECT idx
   FROM OLD
   WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM CODE_MAPPING CM
                   WHERE OLD.CODE_ID = CM.CODE_ID)
3. do foreach on OLD and update NEW

   OPEN MY_CURSOR
   FETCH NEXT FROM MY_CURSOR INTO @IdxId
   WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
   BEGIN

   ```
   SELECT @IdxNew = Min(Idx) -- min to get only one row
     FROM NEW
     INNER JOIN OLD_CODE OLD  ON NEW.MASTER_ID = OLD.MASTER_ID
   WHERE NEW.CODE = 1234 
       AND OLD.IDX = @IdxOld -- current row from old
       AND SEQ_NO=0 -- row not updated yet         

   UPDATE NEW
     SET SEQ_NO = OLD.SEQ_NO,
     CODE_ID = OLD.CODE_ID
   FROM NEW_CODE NEW
     INNER JOIN OLD_CODE  OLD  ON NEW.MASTER_ID = OLD.MASTER_ID
   WHERE NEW.IDX = @IdxNew
     AND OLD.IDX = @IdxOld

   FETCH NEXT FROM MY_CURSOR INTO @IdxId
   ```

   END
   CLOSE MY_CURSOR
   DEALLOCATE MY_CURSOR
4. Drop IDX columns

   alter table OLD drop COLUMN IDX

   alter table NEW drop COLUMN IDX

Comment: This still gets the same result where it just updates Z1 twice as the CODE_ID I need it to update the first row as Z1 then look at the second row with a MASTER_ID of 300 which the CODE_ID is blank and is also not in the CODE_MAPPING table.  So in the expected results the CODE_ID's for the rows should be Z1 and blank.

Comment: Edited my answer, because I needed formatting and to much characters.

Answer (score 0):

The aliases do not match in the update . . . that is `new` is not `new_code`.  Try this:

```
UPDATE NC
  SET SEQ_NO = OC.SEQ_NO,
      CODE_ID = OC.CODE_ID
  FROM NEW_CODE NC INNER JOIN
       OLD_CODE OC
       ON NC.MASTER_ID = OC.MASTER_ID LEFT JOIN
       CODE_MAPPING CM
       ON OC.CODE_ID = CM.CODE_ID
  WHERE NC.CODE = 1234 AND CM.CODE_ID IS NULL;
```

Comment: I had an error in the alias which I just updated good catch but it's the same exact code I have posted.  I am having a problem handling a MASTER_ID that has more then one row.  Right now it just takes the first non NULL CODE_ID that is not in the CODE_MAPPING table and updates all rows that have a CODE of 1234.  I need it to loop through and update it for each CODE_ID that is not in the CODE_MAPPING table.  I'm not sure if I need another INNER JOIN or some sort of a CASE statement....